How to evaluate $S=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-(-1)^{m+n}}{mn(m+n)^3}$?
How can this be evaluated?
$$S=\sum_{m=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-(-1)^{m+n}}{mn(m+n)^3}$$
I tried to turn it into a triple integral but I didn't know how to continue
$$S=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{xyz} \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(xyz)^{n}}{n}\right)^2dxdydz=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{1}{xyz} (\ln(1-xyz))^2dxdydz$$
I derived it from the following integral so I am confident that there is a solution
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\ln^2(1+e^{2ix})dx=\int_0^{\pi/2}x^2\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}e^{2nix}}{n^2}\right)^2dx$$

Is it known to have a solution ?

@mick i edited it

You would face the same kind of problem if you replace the cube by a square.

I think the cube case is harder than the square. And I think the square case has a solution.

What do you mean derived it from that integral ? Is the value of the integral the same or not ?

@mick they are not the same. if you multiply out the sum squared (don't use the Cauchy product) and find the integral, this double sum in question easily follows in addition to some other terms i have already evaluated

@phi-rate sorry ?

You can evaluate this series only series transformation and express by Riemann zeta values $\zeta(s)$. Here is known AMZV(alternative multiple zeta values) expression;
\begin{align}
\zeta(1,4)&=\sum_{0<m<n}\frac1{mn^4}=2\zeta(5)-\zeta(2)\zeta(3),\\
\zeta(1, \bar4)&=\sum_{0<m<n}\frac{(-1)^n}{mn^4}=\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{29}{32}\zeta(5)
\end{align}
Using above,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{0<m,n}\frac{1-(-1)^{m+n}}{mn(m+n)^3}
&=\sum_{0<m,n}\frac{1-(-1)^{m+n}}{(m+n)^4}\left(\frac1m+\frac1n\right)\\
&=2\sum_{0<m<n}\frac{1-(-1)^n}{mn^4}&(m+n\mapsto n)\\
&=2\zeta(1,4)-2\zeta(1,\bar4)\\
&=\frac{93}{16}\zeta(5)-3\zeta(2)\zeta(3).
\end{align*}

Where can I find a proof for those two multiple zeta values?

$\zeta(1,4)$ is evaluated by sum formula for depth $2$, weight $5$; $\zeta(1, 4)+\zeta(2, 3)+\zeta(3,2)=\zeta(5)$, and stuffle product $\zeta(2)\zeta(3)=\zeta(2, 3)+\zeta(3, 2)+\zeta(5)$. I don't know the short proof of evaluation of $\zeta(1, \bar 4)$, but you can see it at https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.03515.  Well, we can prove it by using EDSR(extended double shuffle rerations).

Too long for a comment.
If you are able to compute formally
$$I=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{\log ^2(1-x y z)}{x y z}\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ which is
$$I=\int_{-1}^1\int_0^1 \frac{-2 \text{Li}_3(1-y z)+2 \text{Li}_2(1-y z) \log (1-y z)+\log (y z) \log ^2(1-y z)+2\zeta (3)}{y z}\,dy\,dz$$ you should get the result (which I did not obtain).
On the other hand, if
$$A_m=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-(-1)^{m+n}}{m n (m+n)^3}$$
$$A_m=\frac{\psi ^{(0)}(m+1)-m \psi ^{(1)}(m+1)+\gamma }{m^4}+\frac{\psi ^{(2)}(m+1)}{2 m^2}+$$
$$(-1)^m\Bigg(\frac{\psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{m}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)+2 \log (2)}{2 m^4}+\frac{\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)-\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)}{4 m^2}   +\frac{\psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{m+1}{2}\right)-\psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{m}{2}+1\right)}{16 m^2}\Bigg)$$ does not seem simple to sum.
Computing exactly the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{m=1}^{10^p} A_m$$ and converting to decimals
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & S_p \\
 0 & 0.042704958 \\
 1 & 0.094716604 \\
 2 & 0.095228205 \\
 3 & 0.095229524 \\
 4 & 0.095229526 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ while the numerical value of $I$ is $0.095232490$ (are they the same ?).
Edit
If we write
$$S=\sum_{m=1}^{10} A_m+  \sum_{m=11}^{\infty} A_m=S_1+S_2$$
$$S_1= -\frac{1968329 \zeta (3)}{725760}+\frac{204204138588629}{26464974480000}-\frac{19164113947
   \pi ^2}{64012032000}-\frac{19977010922 \log (2)}{9845600625} $$                                        and for $S_2$ use the series expansion of $A_m$  to $O\left(\frac{1}{m^{10}}\right)$
$$A_m=\Bigg(\frac{2 \log (m)+2 \gamma -3}{2 m^4}+\frac{3}{2 m^5}-\frac{1}{2 m^6}+\frac{1}{8 m^8}+\cdots\Bigg)+$$
$$(-1)^m\,\Bigg(\frac{\log (2)}{ m^4}-\frac{3}{2 m^5}+\frac{3}{2 m^6}-\frac{15}{8 m^8}+\cdots\Bigg)$$
Numerically
$$S_1=0.094716603530792$$
$$S_2=0.000512922536758$$
$$S=S_1+S_2=0.095229526067550$$
